# How to efficiently encode a 1D float32 numpy array in json without loss of precision?

Tags: python, json, numpy, encoding, floating-point

I have a 1D numpy array of type float32. I want to create a JSON file which efficiently encodes the numpy array without degrading the precision. Since JSON is encoded in characters and not numbers, naively converting the array into a string will increase the file size multiple times. Is there a way to efficiently encode the data? Using an existing python module is possible and preferable. Also, encoding without some form of compressing the numpy array into a binary array is desired.

Comment: You seem to conflict yourself quite a bit here. JSON is meant to be text only and usually means increase in size.

Comment: It is not clear whether you want a binary-based solution or a JSON-specific solution. Can you precise that in your question please?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't mind using a custom encoding as long as its lossless. The main issue is file size.

Comment: Ok. The [save and savez](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) functions of Numpy might be of interest for you. The problem with Json is that data is encoded to a text that may not be the exact float value (rounding) but very close to. Keep in mind that float are not always able to precisely represent some numbers. For example, 0.3 is not exactly 0.3 but internally something like 0.299999999999996... (printed as "0.3")